# Create an array of objects recursively based in array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
myArr = [
    { "id": "aaa.bbb" },
    { "id": "aaa.ccc" },
    { "id": "111.222" },
    { "id": "111.333" },
]
```

My goal is to be able to have a new array for every part of the Id, while nesting the old array. Like this:

```
newArray = [
    {
      "id": "aaa",
      "children": [{ "id": "aaa.bbb" }] 
    },
    {
      "id": "aaa",
      "children": [{ "id": "aaa.ccc" }] 
    },
    {...}
]
```

The idea is to be able to do It with multiple substrings if there is a bigger Id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use map to iterate through the array and mutate the objects in place

```js
myArr = [ { "id": "aaa.bbb" }, { "id": "aaa.ccc" }, { "id": "111.222" }, { "id": "111.333" }, ]
result=myArr.map((o)=>({["id"]:o.id.split(".")[0],["children"]:[o]}))
console.log(result)
```

alternatively you could use reduce

```js
myArr = [ { "id": "aaa.bbb" }, { "id": "aaa.ccc" }, { "id": "111.222" }, { "id": "111.333" }, ]
result=myArr.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc=[...acc,{["id"]:curr.id.split(".")[0],["children"]:[curr]}],[])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.prototype.map`.

```
const newArray = myArr.map( function( e ) {

    const oldId = e.id;    
    const newElement = {
        id: oldId.split( '.' )[0],
        children: [ e ]
    };
    return newElement
} );
```

Simplified:

```
const newArray = myArr.map( function( e ) {
    return {
        id: e.id.split( '.' )[0],
        children: [ e ]
    };
} );
```

Further:

```
const newArray = myArr.map( e => { id: e.id.split( '.' )[0], children: [ e ] } );
```